# How can I solve the billing tier problem occured when I wanna add more value than the previous max blank into the next min blank?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

While trying add one more value than the previous max blank into the next min blank on bottom row, I receive nothing. No expected sequent value appears there. [Here's my HTML.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXcai.jpg) Actually I can see the right values on the console but it doesn't work on HTML inputs.

Please look at that. What the other ways do I use to fix it?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.exchangeRate').select2();
        var i = 0;
        var tierPrices = [];
        var tierProperty;
        var min = $("#min" + i + "").val();
        $('#addtier').click(function () {
            
            if (i == 0) {
                tierProperty = {
                    "Min": min,
                    "Max": $("#max" + i + "").val(),
                    "StartDate": $("#startdate" + i + "").val(),
                    "EndDate": $("#enddate" + i + "").val()
                };
            } else {
                i--;
                min = $("#max" + i + "").val();
                min = parseInt(min) + 1;
                i++;
                tierProperty = {
                    "Min": min,
                    "Max": $("#max" + i + "").val(),
                    "StartDate": $("#startdate" + i + "").val(),
                    "EndDate": $("#enddate" + i + "").val()
                };
            }
            i++;
            var rowElement = `<div class="row" id="row${i}">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>MIN:</label>
                                        <input type="number" placeholder="0" class="form-control"  id="min${i}" value="${min}" readonly>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>MAX:</label>
                                        <input type="number" placeholder="Max" class="form-control" id="max${i}">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Başlangıç Tarihi:</label>
                                        <input type="date" placeholder="gg.aa.yyyy" class="form-control" id="startdate${i}">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Bitiş Tarihi:</label>
                                        <input type="date" placeholder="gg.aa.yyyy" class="form-control" id="enddate${i}">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <button type="button" name="remove" class="btn bg-danger-400 btn-float legitRipple btn_remove" id="${i}"><i class="icon-subtract" ></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>`;


            tierPrices.push(tierProperty);
            console.log(tierPrices);
            $('#tierform').append(rowElement);


        })
        $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function () {
            var buttonId = $(this).attr('id');
            console.log(buttonId);
            $("#row" + buttonId + "").remove();
            i--;
        })
        $("#submit").click(function () {
            if (i == 0) {
                tierProperty = {
                    "Min": $("#min" + i + "").val(),
                    "Max": $("#max" + i + "").val(),
                    "StartDate": $("#startdate" + i + "").val(),
                    "EndDate": $("#enddate" + i + "").val()
                };
            } else {
                i--;
                min = $("#max" + i + "").val();
                i++;
                tierProperty = {
                    "Min": min,
                    "Max": $("#max" + i + "").val(),
                    "StartDate": $("#startdate" + i + "").val(),
                    "EndDate": $("#enddate" + i + "").val()
                };
            }
            tierPrices.push(tierProperty);
            console.log(tierPrices);

    })
```